# What does this CSS syntax mean?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**What does this mean: `[class*="col-"]`** If you could give me a link to w3schools or explain it to me. How does this syntax work? I never saw it in the tutorials. I understand everything except that syntax.

```css
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 15px;
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<h1>Chania</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-3">
<ul>
<li>The Flight</li>
<li>The City</li>
<li>The Island</li>
<li>The Food</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="col-9">
<h1>The City</h1>
<p>Chania is the capital of the Chania region on the island of Crete. The city can be divided in two parts, the old town and the modern city.</p>
<p>Resize the browser window to see how the content respond to the resizing.</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a selector which will apply styles to all those elements which has class name  containing col-

Comment: search for `CSS Attribute selectors`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means it is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> Select any element contains at least one occurrence of `col-` as its class value.

So `[class*="col-"]` would match classnames like: `col-1`, `col-2`, `col-one-two`, `one-col-one`

Comment: It's not a class selector, it's an attribute selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` brackets is an attribute selector.

That would mean for a line of code as

```
<div class="col-"></div>
```

writing `div[class="col-"]` would select all the `div` with class `col-`

Answer (score 0):

`class[*="col-"]` selects any elements whose class name **contains** the substring 'col-' such as `<div class='my-col-class'>`, `<div class='col-sm-8'>`, etc.

If you want to select all classes whose class name **begins** with col-, you'd use `class[^="col-"]`.

Likewise, to find all classes that **end** with col-, you'd use `class[$="col-"]`.

Comment: `class` is an attribute. It would go inside the brackets.

Comment: I so knew that, I've no idea why I put it outside. Ugh. Shame me.